# Dockerfile COPY copies only one subdirectory of a directory it should copy

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have directory structure like this:

```
opt
  - dcmtk-3.6.5-linux-x86_64-static
    | - bin    
    | - etc
    | - share
```

In each of there subdirectories there are also some files.

In `Dockerfile` I have line

```
COPY opt/* /opt/
```

But when I create container from this image, and run `/bin/bash`, and go to `/opt` and run `ls -al` I can see there is only `bin` directory, with it's content. No `dcmtk-3.6.5-linux-x86_64-static` directory, no other subdirectories like `etc` or `share`.

There are also some other files I keep in `opt`, those are copied just as expected.

Why isn't whole `dcmtk-3.6.5-linux-x86_64-static` copied?

Answer (score 1):

Extracts from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) (in relevant order for my answer)

> If multiple <src> resources are specified, **either directly or due to the use of a wildcard**, then <dest> must be a directory, and it must end with a slash /
>
> [...]
>
> If <src> is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, including filesystem metadata.
>
> **Note: The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.**

Solution:

```
COPY opt /opt/
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) says:

> If <src> is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, including filesystem metadata.

So you should use the following:

```
COPY opt /opt
```

Just leave out the `/*` and specify only the directory.

**Edit 01.10.2020**:

Just tried again with the following setup:

```
ls -lR
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 peter  staff   34  1 Okt 13:06 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x  4 peter  staff  128  1 Okt 13:01 opt

./opt:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 peter  staff   64  1 Okt 13:01 emptydir
drwxr-xr-x  4 peter  staff  128  1 Okt 13:01 foo

./opt/emptydir:

./opt/foo:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 peter  staff  96  1 Okt 13:01 bar
-rw-r--r--  1 peter  staff   0  1 Okt 13:01 foo.txt

./opt/foo/bar:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 peter  staff  0 29 Sep 19:15 bar.txt
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox:latest
COPY opt /opt
```

building the image:

```
docker build -t so-test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/2 : FROM busybox:latest
 ---> 6858809bf669
Step 2/2 : COPY opt /opt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f6f2692b571a
Successfully built f6f2692b571a
Successfully tagged so-test:latest
```

running the container:

```
docker run -it so-test /bin/sh
/ #
```

and checking what's in there:

```
# ls -lR /opt
/opt:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Oct  1 11:01 emptydir
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Oct  1 11:01 foo

/opt/emptydir:
total 0

/opt/foo:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Oct  1 11:01 bar
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct  1 11:01 foo.txt

/opt/foo/bar:
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Sep 29 17:15 bar.txt
```

So the whole directory structure was copied, including the empty directory.
There must be something interfering in you setup

Comment: seems we posted nearly the same answer at nearly the same time!

Comment: So it worked as it was COPY /opt/dcmtk-3.6.5-linux-x86_64-static ? Ok, understood. Still, doesn't answer why etc and share subdirs were not copied.

Comment: i tried it and it copied the subdirectories; are these empty in your setup?

Comment: Nope, each of them has files inside